# Error in R with GA-package fitness function

Tags: r, genetic-algorithm

I use an example from the GA-package about LM feature selection, but I want to add a penalty, so that it is not possible to have an amount of features selected that is above a certain threshold.

In this example I add a penalty 'sum(string*-1)*100', so for every feature selected there is a penalty of 100.

But if I run the code I get an error:
"Error in x[, ii] : subscript out of bounds"

What is wrong with my code or with the package?

(If the line "-BIC(mod)+sum(string*-1)*100  # fitness function value" of code is changed to "-BIC(mod)  # fitness function value" then everything runs fine...)

```
 library(GA)

 data(fat, package = "UsingR")
 mod <- lm(body.fat.siri ~ age + weight + height + neck + chest + abdomen + hip + thigh + knee + ankle + bicep + forearm + wrist, data = fat)
 summary(mod)
 x <- model.matrix(mod)[,-1]
 y <- model.response(mod$model)

 fitness <- function(string)
 { 
   mod <- lm(y ~ x[,string==1])
  -BIC(mod)+sum(string*-1)*100  # fitness function value
 }
 GA = ga("binary", fitness = fitness, nBits = ncol(x), popSize = 100, maxiter = 100, monitor = FALSE)
 summary(GA)
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is actually occurring on the previous line 
`mod <- lm(y ~ x[,string==1])`.

Modify your fitness function to print out the string

```
fitness <- function(string) { 
   mod <- lm(y ~ x[,string==1])
   -BIC(mod)+sum(string*-1)*100  # fitness function value
}
```

and run the ga. You will see that this consistently occurs when string is all zeros.

Test directly.

```
string = rep(0,13)
fitness(string)
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
Error in x[, ii] : subscript out of bounds

mod <- lm(y ~ x[,string==1])
Error in x[, ii] : subscript out of bounds
```

The problem is that you are trying to fit a linear model with NO predictor variables. When you include this penalty term, it drives the number of variables to zero. Without that term, you are unlikely to test all zeros.